# Powershell: How to grab substring of text

Tags: regex, powershell, substring, contains

I have a field, `description` which contains text in a predictable format, which looks like either 1 of these 2 options,

```
DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 02 2019
```

or

```
DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 02 2019 | MANAGER John Smith
```

I need to grab just the date in each case, `Tue Apr 02 2019`, while accounting for there either being or not being text after the date.

Example use case

```
$string = "DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 02 2019 | MANAGER John Smith"
$date   = "Tue Apr 02 2019"
```

Comment: Have you already attempted to solve this yourself? If so please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56060672/edit) and post the code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got it since I had to account for some potential differences across objects

```
$text = "DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 02 2019 | MANAGER John Smith"
$start_pos = $text.IndexOf('on')

$substring = $text.substring($start_pos + 3)

if ($text.IndexOf(' | ') -gt -1) {
    $end_pos = $text.indexOf(' | ')
    $substring = $substring.substring(0, $end_pos)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly but substring works like this:

```
$string = "DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 02 2019 | MANAGER John Smith"
#.substring(starting point, how many)
$date = $string.Substring(15,10)
$date
Tue Apr 02
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly different way to do the job. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- the 1st 4 lines create an array of strings to work with
- iterates thru the collection
- splits on the '|'
- takes the 1st item in the resulting array
- trims away any leading/trailing whitespace
- uses a named capture group to get the date string after `DEACTIVATED on`
- shows the resulting named capture group
- converts that to a `[datetime]` object & displays that

here's the code ...

```
$DescriptionText = @(
    'DEACTIVATED on Sat May 11 2019'
    'DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 02 2019 | MANAGER John Smith'
    )

foreach ($DT_Item in $DescriptionText)
    {
    $Null = $DT_Item.Split('|')[0].Trim() -match 'DEACTIVATED on (?<DeactivationDate>.+)'

    $Matches.DeactivationDate
    [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches.DeactivationDate, 'ddd MMM dd yyyy', $Null)
    '=' * 20
    }
```

the output ...

```
Sat May 11 2019

2019 May 11, Saturday 12:00:00 AM
====================
Tue Apr 02 2019
2019 April 02, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
====================
```

i can't figure out where the blank line in the 1st pair of outputs comes from. [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

- a regular expression with a [positive lookbehind zero length assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- cast/convert to [datetime] type with `::ParseExact()`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\09\SO_56060672.ps1

$strings = @"
DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 02 2019

DEACTIVATED on Tue Apr 09 2019 | MANAGER John Smith
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$RE = '(?<=DEACTIVATED on ).*\d{4}'

## Output found datetime strings
$strings | Select-String $RE | ForEach-Object{$_.Matches.value}

## if your locale is English convert to [datetime] type
$strings | Select-String $RE | ForEach-Object{
    [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Matches.value,'ddd MMM dd yyyy',$null)
}

## if your locale is NOT English convert to [datetime] type
$strings | Select-String $RE | ForEach-Object{
    [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Matches.value,'ddd MMM dd yyyy',
       [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
}
```

Output of the first & last in my German locale:

```
Tue Apr 02 2019
Tue Apr 09 2019

Dienstag, 2. April 2019 00:00:00
Dienstag, 9. April 2019 00:00:00
```